# Session variables across pages

Tags: php, variables, session

So i've created a login form which passes variables to login.php

Login.php

```
<?php
{
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from patient_details WHERE email LIKE '{$email}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        header('Location: dashboard.php');

    }
}
?>
```

The login check works perfect... But the session variables doesn't work. So i tried to echo it in login.php. It works there.. But it doesnt work on another page. In this case dashboard.php

Dashboard.php

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['email']; // green

?>
```

Comment: are you calling `session_start();` on `login.php`? You must start the session before writing to or reading from the session and before any output is sent to the browser

Comment: Do you not need to call `session_start()` on login.php too?

Comment: Where should i put the session_start(); on login.php?

Comment: just put it at the top after `<?php`

Comment: ASAP.  The usual approach would probably to put this sort of thing in a global file that's required for every request, so you don't need to put it in every page

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). This is  doubly bad since you're doing a login system, for a medical system...

Comment: You also _appear_ to be storing unhashed/unencrypted passwords

Comment: @MarcB ouch, yeah, I didnt even look at that, I was just looking at the session issue

Comment: If you're dealing with something like banking or medical system, use server-side Java with proper MVC approach, not PHP.  PHP is for stuff where security ain't so important. Just a tip.

Comment: Unless you run session_start (), $_SESSION is just another local variable.

Comment: No this ain't for an actual medical system.. It's for computer students. It isn't that critical